# Parse SOAP API using php

Tags: php, arrays, xml, api, soap

I am a beginner at SOAP and have been trying to figure how to get get a proper response when I call the SOAP API. I have tried diff method since last 3 days but still have no idea. I have already tried similar questions like this on stackoverflow but somehow they are not working for me.

I really appreciated your help or response how I may be able to get this done.

Here's the sample request that I should send:

```
POST /wsror/Form.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.159.159.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://apps.in/wsror/GetAllVill"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetAllVill xmlns="http://apps.in/wsror">
      <strTaluka>string</strTaluka>
      <Username>string</Username>
      <Password>string</Password>
    </GetAllVill>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

here's the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetAllVillResponse xmlns="http://apps.in/wsror">
      <GetAllVillResult>dataset</GetAllVillResult>
    </GetAllVillResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have tried fetching response by using below method:

```
$soapclient = new SoapClient('sensitive info');

$param=array('sensitive info');
$response =$soapclient->GetAllVill($param);
var_dump($response);
```

and I get below response:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["GetAllVillResult"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["any"]=> string(6596) "19200Adco 24000Bandora 3001000600020700Beto 30010tqui 001900Bma 300100060Borim 600019Capar  " } }
```

Comment: Can you provide the original XML response of the webservice?

Comment: I have added it now.

Comment: Is "dataset" really a string? Or are there elements in CDATA?

Comment: @Marcel: It is a string

Comment: Your xml and your `response` don't contain the same data. Can you edit your question and show the way the xml looks before any processing?

Comment: In your actual xml there are no "19200Adco, 24000Bandora etc"; so what exactly is your expected output?

Comment: @JackFleeting: The output which i'm getting after parsing is "object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["GetAllVillagesInaTalukaResult"]=> object(stdC ...etc" I just want following data as output "19200Adco, 24000Bandora etc";  I have been stuck at this problem for last 2 days and I'm not getting any good sources to resolve this issue as well.

Comment: As I said in the previous comment - the data you are looking for is NOT in the xml, so I'm not sure where they come from.

Comment: @JackFleeting :I have modified my question now ,hoping that you might better understand the issue.

Comment: I think I understand now; can you edit your question and show the output of `$response->asXML();` ?

Comment: @JackFleeting: I tried doing var_dump($response->asXML()); but there was no output. so I tried  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
echo $xml->asXML();... for this I got output=>SimpleXMLElement::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given.

Comment: OK; try of these two (or both...) - either `$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->loadXML($response);
echo $xmlDoc->saveXML();` or `$xmlDoc = simplexml_load_string($response);
echo $xmlDoc->asXML();` and if you get anything, edit your question with the output.

Comment: @JackFleeting: I tried both. There is no output.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I'm out of ideas :(

Comment: @JackFleeting: I tried running var_dump($client->__getTypes());  and  I got following output => struct GetAll { string strTaluka; string Username; string Password; }" [40]=> string(104) "struct GetAllVillResponse { GetAllVillResult}"...does this help?

Comment: If you try to echo XML to a browser directly, it will try to interpret it as HTML. View the page source, or escape it appropriately.

Comment: @IMSoP I have resolved this issue. I have used curl method, It is not duplicate of the question which you have marked. Please open the question again so that I can close it with correct answer.

Comment: @JackFleeting:Thanks for trying. I resolved this issue. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used curls to finally solve this issue.

```
$url = "http://apps.in/wsror?wsdl";

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetAllVill xmlns="http://apps.in/wsror">
 <strTaluka>code</strTaluka>
      <Username>Username</Username>
      <Password>Password</Password>
    </GetAllVill>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

$headers = array(
    "Content-type: text/xml",
    "Content-length: " . strlen($xml),
    "Connection: close",
);

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = curl_exec($ch); 
//echo $data;

  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadXML($data);
```

and then looped through the required tags.

```
$VILLAGES = $doc->getElementsByTagName('VILLAGES');
foreach ($VILLAGES as $VILLAGE) {
    $VillageName = $VILLAGE->getElementsByTagName('VillageName')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $Village = $VILLAGE->getElementsByTagName('Village')->item(0)->nodeValue;
   // $id = $VILLAGE->getElementsByTagName('taluka')->item(0)->nodeValue;
 echo '<option  value="'.htmlentities($Village, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8").'" >'.htmlentities($VillageName, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8").'</option> ';
}
```